# What would be the most complete procedure to get a simple login system working securely?

Tags: authentication, session-management, hmac, access-token

I don't have formal CS education but i've written one or 2 little websites. I have troubles communicating even in my native language but i hope this is understandable.

With simple i mean something like we have a single server to authenticate the clients, a client provides an username and a password and clients would be let to stay logged in up to 1 week if they don't log out by themselves.

From what i understand of what i've read:

1. Prompt the user to give an email, username, password, password confirmation and answer a bot detection challenge.
2. Client strips special characters and sends 5 encrypted answers to the server.
3. Server checks if the username or email are in use, if not, generate a registration token with expiration time via email.
4. Client uses registration token manually or uses registration link.
5. Redirect user to login page.
6. User gives username, password and answers a bot detection challenge.
7. Client strips special characters and sends 3 encrypted answers to the server and a) [] or b) PKCE hash and stores PKCE in RAM?.
8. Server checks credentials, if pass, [if b) store pkce hash and] returns encrypted a) session cookie and CSRF token or b) refresh and access token and redirects to protected page.
9. Client stores a) session cookie and CSRF token in httponly cookie or b) refresh token, access token and new PKCE in RAM?.
10. From the protected page, client sends a request together with a) session cookie and CSRF token or b) access token, 7)'s PKCE and 9)'s PKCE hash.
11. Server checks if a) session cookie and csrf token or b) access token and hash of 7)'s PKCE passed in 10) are in server storage, if so, answer the request and return a) new CSRF token or b) new access token.

11.b2) Else if only the access token expired, return an expired token error and wait for refresh token and 9)'s PKCE.

11.b3) Client sends request again together with refresh token, 9)'s PKCE and new PKCE hash.

11.b4) Server checks if refresh token and hash of 9)'s PKCE passed in 11.b3) are in server storage, if so, answer the request and return new access token.

12. If user logs out, flag a) session cookie and csrf token or b) refresh and access token as expired until expiration date.

Is there a right thing to do in 2) and 6) or it is opinion based? i've read that some strip special characters, others encode them or do nothing and i don't see many sites using captchas for login.

I would say i'm sure that PKCE and access token are stored in RAM but what to do when the browser or app is closed? There's controversy about the refresh token, some say to not store any token which means login every time that it's closed, others say store the refresh token but don't say where nor how and if they say it there's a comment right below saying it's insecure, do i store it like a session cookie? but there is the answer of this:
[Are HTTPonly cookies secure enough for implementing "remember me" functionality?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/174702/are-httponly-cookies-secure-enough-for-implementing-remember-me-functionality)
that says not even httponly cookies are secure, which would mean step 9) is completely wrong.

In which steps signature keys are passed?

If i have to store tokens in the server why is it called stateless?

Is this secure? if not, what should i modify?

I know there's OpenID Connect and OAuth2 but i can't use them.

Comment: Why do you strip special characters? This way you may weaken the complexity of the password used. Also, the code run at the client side is under the control of the client and can be modified. So the output you expect from steps (2) and (7) may not be the one actually sent to the server.

Comment: @Spyros Thanks for taking time to say something, I'll clarify, I'm asking how it's done, not saying that it is or should be done that way.